# How to link a post to its category in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, post, hyperlink, categories

I want to add a link when my post gets click on. The link has to go to the category of the post. I've got this far but now I'm stuck. Can anyone show me how I can do this?

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'category_name'  => 'portriats',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);
$qry = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $qry->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $qry->have_posts() ) : $qry->the_post();
        $postcat = get_the_category( $post->ID );
        ?>

        <div class="hometile">
            <a href="<?php get_category_link( $postcat) ?>">
                ==> **I need to get the category of the post and then let PHP print the link of the categorey in the href**
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </a>
        </div>

        <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**It will display primary category of post with link**

```
<?php $qry = new WP_Query($args ); ?>
<?php if ( $qry->have_posts() ) : ?>

  <?php while ( $qry->have_posts() ) : $qry->the_post(); $postcat = get_the_category();?>
 <div class="hometile">
  <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $postcat[0]->term_id ); ?>">
   <?php echo $postcat[0]->name; ?>
   <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
  </a>

 </div>

 <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```